# Отложенный запрос python + flask + mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Всем привет. Есть идеи, как реализовать следующий сценарий. Есть пользователь, у которого постоянно обновляются данные о местоположении. Нужно реализовать удаление пользователя, если его данные не обновлялись, к примеру, 30 минут. python + flask + mysql + sqlachemy

Comment: Соответствующая event procedure в MySQL.

Comment: К примеру в sql могу задать команду: SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE dateupdate < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE). Во фласк я могу вызывать данную команду, к примеру, каждые 10 минут?

Comment: А нахрена делать это во фласке, когда сервер БД может это делать без каких-либо внешних инструментов? каждую хоть минуту, хоть секунду.

Comment: Согласен, прописал в события mysql, можно даже через конструктор phpmyadmin